# Angular 4 - Pass component input from route

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out how to pass parameter to component when declaring the routes.

```js
{ 
    path: 'registration',
    component: RegistrationComponent,
    data: { title: 'Registration' },
    canActivate: [GuestOnlyGuard]
  }
  
  export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() mode: string = 'default';
  @Input() showSubmitBtn: boolean = true;
  @Input() showLoginNavigationLink: boolean = true;
  @Output('onComplete') completed: EventEmitter<UserRegistrationInfo> = new EventEmitter<UserRegistrationInfo>();
/...... Implementation........./
}
```

I want to pass a specific mode to registration component when component is loaded from route.

Comment: you can use `data` the way you have with `titel`, @Input and @Output don't work with components used with `router`

Comment: use `:param` with your route and then navigate to it with value you want to pass to it. https://angular.io/guide/router